# angular wait for function from rootscope

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an app which requires the user to login. After a succesfull login, the user will be saved in a session and everytime when the user comes back, there will be checked if the session is valid. That works.

But I have some elements on my page which, of course, are not visible to the public. I did that with `ng-show="!user"`. I also added some `ng-init` attributes to that element which does a function to load some items.

That function is triggered before the `checkLogin()` function from the `$rootScope` is done, so I'm getting errors because `$rootScope.user` is undefined.

I can add more checks for `$rootScope.user` but then the function does nothing because he is triggered one time.

How can I change the function that the whole app wait for it before continues?

```
$rootScope.checkLogin = function(welcome){
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: 'api/check-login',
    })
    .then(function(response){
        if(response.data.success){
            $rootScope.user = response.data.data.user;
            if(welcome){
                return $rootScope.showToast("Hallo, " + response.data.data.user.user_name + "!"); 
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 inner pages:

1. loading page
2. main page

if rootScope.user is undefined, display the loading page, otherwise display the main.

There are lots of other solutions in the same concept ([splash screens](http://embed.plnkr.co/twGP7gUe9uraYXSr6kQG/), [spinners](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner)...)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own promise and resolve it on the success function:

```
        $rootScope.checkLogin = function(welcome) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: 'api/check-login'
            }).then(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.data.success){
                        $rootScope.user = response.data.data.user;

                        var message = welcome ? $rootScope.showToast("Hallo, " + response.data.data.user.user_name + "!") : '';
                        deferred.resolve(message);
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject();
                    }
            }, function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Then you can call `$rootScope.checkLogin` and wait for the promise:

```
        $rootScope.checkLogin(true).then(
            function(response) {
                // success
            },
            function() {
                // failure
            }
        );
```